# Date Difference, T-SQL, multiple rows for ticketing system

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to get a stored procedure to calculate the amount of time a ticket was open, including multiple closes and opens. My data looks like this:

```
      FeedbackID    Open/Closed TimeStamp
      2145          Open        2015-11-16 20:23:49.750
      2145          Closed      2015-11-23 12:00:35.087
      2146          Open        2015-11-16 21:44:59.020
      2146          Closed      2015-11-17 12:24:55.843
      2146          Open        2015-12-04 13:43:41.830
      2146          Closed      2015-12-04 13:45:04.410
      2147          Open        2015-11-17 02:39:41.263
      2147          Closed      2015-11-23 22:11:33.490
```

As you can see the FeedbackID #2146 has 4 events. I need to be able to calculate the difference between each Open and Closed event and then add them up if there are more than 2 Open and Closed Events. Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: Posting the code for the procedure below

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetOpenCloseFeedbackEvents]    
    AS
    BEGIN

    DECLARE @TempTable TABLE (FeedbackID int, [Open/Closed] varchar(20), [TimeStamp] datetime)
    DECLARE @UIDTable TABLE (FeedBackID int, [UID] uniqueidentifier)
    DECLARE @Open Table (FeedbackID int, [Open/Closed] varchar(20), [TimeStamp] datetime)
    DECLARE @Closed Table (FeedbackID int, [Open/Closed] varchar(20), [TimeStamp] datetime)

-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO @TempTable (FeedbackID, [Open/Closed], [TimeStamp])
SELECT * FROM dbo.FeedbackChange
WHERE FeedbackID = FeedbackChange.FeedbackID
AND
[Open/Closed] IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY FeedbackID

INSERT INTO @UIDTable (FeedBackID, [UID])
SELECT FeedbackID, [UID] FROM tblFeedbackRequests fbr
where fbr.FeedbackID = FeedbackID

SELECT * FROM @TempTable t
--JOIN @UIDTable u ON t.FeedbackID = u.FeedBackID
--WHERE u.UID = @UID
Order by t.FeedbackID

SELECT FeedbackID, [Open/Closed], TimeStamp, 
       ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by FeedBackID order by TimeStamp asc) as [Indicator]
INTO @Open
FROM @TempTable
Where [Open/Closed] = 'Open'

SELECT FeedbackID, [Open/Closed], TimeStamp, 
       ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by FeedBackID order by TimeStamp asc) as [Indicator]
INTO @Closed
FROM @TempTable
Where [Open/Closed] = 'Closed'

SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(day,o.TimeStamp,c.TimeStamp)) as "Days Open",
       o.FeedbackID
FROM   @Open o
INNER JOIN @Closed c on o.FeedbackID = c.FeedbackID and o.[Indicator = c.Indicator
GROUP BY   o.FeedbackID
```

END

Comment: Why `more than 2 Open and Closed Events`?

Comment: What should be returned for `FeedbackID = 2146`?

Comment: Can you redesign the app to have an additional column that stores the time the ticket was open? You could populate it whenever it is set to closed. Then, it would just be a matter of "group by" and "total".

Comment: Or, maybe have these 3 columns instead: FeedbackID, OpenTimeStamp, ClosedTimeStamp.  This would simplify your calculations.

Comment: Why more than 2? Because a ticket could be closed and opened many times.

Comment: I could restructure the procedure to have 3 columns, that would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make a temp table or CTE for open statuses, and another for closed statuses.  Use `ROW_NUMBER over (partition by FeedBackID order by TimeStamp asc)` to create an indicator of which *open* status records match which *closed* records:

```
SELECT FeedbackID, [Open/Closed], TimeStamp, 
       ROW_NUMBER over (partition by FeedBackID order by TimeStamp asc) as "Indicator"
INTO @Open
FROM Table
WHERE [Open/Closed] = 'Open'

SELECT FeedbackID, [Open/Closed], TimeStamp, 
       ROW_NUMBER over (partition by FeedBackID order by TimeStamp asc) as "Indicator"
INTO @Closed
FROM Table
WHERE [Open/Closed] = 'Closed'
```

Then `JOIN` these tables on `FeedbackID` and `Indicator` and do your date aggregation.  This will allow us to be sure that the earliest *open* record matches up with the earliest *closed* record for each `FeedbackID`:

```
SELECT     SUM(DATEDIFF(day,o.TimeStamp,c.TimeStamp)) as "Days Open",
           o.FeedbackID
FROM       @Open o
INNER JOIN @Closed c on o.FeedbackID = c.FeedbackID and o.Indicator = c.Indicator
GROUP BY   o.FeedbackID
```

At this point you should have your `TimeStamp` differences, wrapped in a `SUM()` and grouping by `FeedbackID` for the cases where a `FeedbackID` has more than 1 open/closed set.

**Edit: Accounting for cases that are still open**

To handle cases that are still open, we first need to change our `INNER JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN` so we don't lose the 'open' records that lack a matching 'closed' record.

```
SELECT     SUM(DATEDIFF(day,o.TimeStamp,c.TimeStamp)) as "Days Open",
           o.FeedbackID
FROM       @Open o
LEFT JOIN  @Closed c on o.FeedbackID = c.FeedbackID and o.Indicator = c.Indicator
GROUP BY   o.FeedbackID
```

However, this will populate `c.TimeStamp` with `null` where cases are still open.  To handle these, we can use `COALESCE()` to replace the `null` `c.TimeStamp` field with something more meaningful.  Since these cases are still open, we might as well use `GETDATE()` and calculate how long they have been open that way:

```
SELECT     SUM(DATEDIFF(day,o.TimeStamp,COALESCE(c.TimeStamp,GETDATE()))) as "Days Open",
           o.FeedbackID
FROM       @Open o
LEFT JOIN  @Closed c on o.FeedbackID = c.FeedbackID and o.Indicator = c.Indicator
GROUP BY   o.FeedbackID
```

Comment: good solution. but use double-quotes or `[]` (in tsql) to enclose the column-aliases, instead of single-quotes.

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something but its telling me that the column names are invalid (FeedbackID etc.) The procedure that I created outputs the data in my original post. I need this procedure to get the data as I have it, and I'm trying to add your suggestion after my code.

Comment: @abramhill Broad answer here is add a `into @table` line into what you have now, then adjust the first part of my answer to pull from `@table`.  You just need to store those results in a table of some kind so that it can be queried.  If you need specific help with it, edit your question and provide the procedure you currently have.

Comment: @AaronD I've edited my question with the full procedure. Thanks so much for this

Comment: @AaronD I did some tweaking and got the code to work! Thanks so much for your help I will post my answer as well just in case anyone wants to see.

Comment: @abramhill Happy to help and glad to hear you got it working - Welcome to Stack Overflow

Comment: @AaronD Only thing I have left to do is to account for when there is only an Open event (Ticket is still open) :)

Comment: @abramhill Updated answer

Comment: @AaronD Thats perfect! I feel bad when I keep coming back to you but there are some scenarios that are giving me trouble. If the case was opened and close within less than an hour I don't get any meaningful data, is there a way to use the DATEDIFF with DATETIME? And in cases that have 3 or more Open/Close events the SUM breaks down. Thanks again for all your help

Comment: @abramhill no worries.  Hmm I'm confused about the sum breaking down - it should calculate the day difference then sum and group on `FeedBackID`, even if there are 100 are open/close events.  Explain how it's breaking down in a little more detail, I'm probably missing something.  As for `DATEDIFF`, my answer uses `day` but you can use `hour` or `minute` or even `second` if you want.  I'd say try each and decide which is best for you.  More info here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

Comment: You might consider using `minute` then `*60` to convert that to hours.  Then you don't lose data where a case is open less than an hour, but you also don't get 18429 minutes for long cases, you get 72.13 hours or whatever.  (Completely random numbers for example)

Comment: @AaronD I dug into my code and realised that I was casting the SUM to an int before pulling it from the website. Your code is perfect!
And yes you were right, I actually used `second` and divided by 3600 to get the decimals I needed. Once again thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final answer with the help of Aaron D.
Thanks for all the help :)

```
    DECLARE @TempTable TABLE (FeedbackID int, [Open/Closed] varchar(20), [TimeStamp] datetime)
    DECLARE @UIDTable TABLE (FeedBackID int, [UID] uniqueidentifier)
    DECLARE @Open Table (FeedbackID int, [Open/Closed] varchar(20), [TimeStamp] datetime, [Indicator] int)
    DECLARE @Closed Table (FeedbackID int, [Open/Closed] varchar(20), [TimeStamp] datetime, [Indicator] int)

-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO @TempTable (FeedbackID, [Open/Closed], [TimeStamp])
SELECT * FROM dbo.FeedbackChange
WHERE FeedbackID = FeedbackChange.FeedbackID
AND
[Open/Closed] IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY FeedbackID

INSERT INTO @UIDTable (FeedBackID, [UID])
SELECT FeedbackID, [UID] FROM tblFeedbackRequests fbr
where fbr.FeedbackID = FeedbackID

INSERT INTO @Open (FeedbackID, [Open/Closed], [TimeStamp],Indicator)
SELECT FeedbackID, [Open/Closed], TimeStamp, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by FeedBackID order by TimeStamp asc) as [Indicator]
FROM @TempTable
Where [Open/Closed] = 'Open'

INSERT INTO @Closed (FeedbackID, [Open/Closed], [TimeStamp],Indicator)
SELECT FeedbackID, [Open/Closed], TimeStamp, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by FeedBackID order by TimeStamp asc) as [Indicator]
FROM @TempTable
Where [Open/Closed] = 'Closed'

SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(HOUR,o.TimeStamp,c.TimeStamp)) as "Days Open", o.FeedbackID
FROM @Open o 
INNER JOIN @Closed c on o.FeedbackID = c.FeedbackID and o.[Indicator] = c.Indicator
GROUP BY o.FeedbackID
```